# Установка https на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, https

Настроил бесплатные SSL сертификаты для сайта, поставил голый wordpress последней версии,в конфиге прописал параметры WP_HOME, WP_SITEURL где указал домен с https а так же FORCE_SSL_ADMIN как true для https в админке.  Wordpress установился, но все ссылки остались с http т.е. к сайту не подключен ни один css, js и медиафайл, т.е. вижу голый html с кучей ошибок в консоли. В БД в таблице wp_options параметры siteurl и home тоже верные http://joxi.ru/KAgKz4BcgowEMA. В при попытке войти в админку /wp-admin/ вообще получаю циклическую переадресацию (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS).

Что не так? Вопросы к хостингу, что-то не правильно настроено в SSL или же нужно что-то ещё настроить в wordpress?

Comment: Интересно, по какой причине заминусован мой ответ. Я неоднократно переносил сайты на https и ответ дан на основании собственного опыта.

Comment: А почему специализированные плагины не используете - Really Simple SSL, например? Я в своё время попробовал - очень удобно и быстро получается.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress хранит все внутренние ссылки как абсолютные. Первое, что нужно сделать, заменить все http://mysite.com на https://mysite.com в базе. Лучше это делать с помощью Search and Replace https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ (потому что эта утилита способна работать с сериализованными данными)

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с подобной проблемой. Решение очень простой. В файле .htaccess добавляем строчку:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
```

Answer (score 0):

**Возможны проблемы на хостинге. В панели управления может стоять, что-то вроде http redirect to https, можно попробовать включить/отключить.**

Лучший вариант ставить сразу на https.

по поводу замены в базе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587244/370520, часто сталкиваюсь стем, что подобные плагины (очень удобные) не срабатывают, не могу сказать почему именно. Самый действенный способ, замена в дампе базы.

Если это бесплатный сертификат от cloudflarer (соотв и dns-proxy включен) - то может помочь плагин исправления редиректа, но не от команды cloudflare - почему-то он часто не справляется с редиректами http->https
upd. по поводу cloudflare. еще может быть проблема двойного редиректа https с cloudflare - на хостинге включен сертификат, например на рег.ру, может быть также включен редирект с http.  если стоит валидный, например бесплатный lets`encrypt, то на cloudflare нужно переключить режим ssl на full strict